# What to use for logging errors in a Quartz scheduled Job?

Tags: error-handling, quartz-scheduler, elmah, quartz.net, error-logging

I have an asp.net mvc 3 application. In this application I have a reminder system that uses quartz to grab messages from the database and send them out.

I am wondering what is the best way to log if something happens(say the database times out - I want to know about this).

I use in my mvc application ELMAH for my logging and it works great. However since quartz.net is it's own thread with out the httpcontext I can't use ELMAH(or at least I don't think I can). I tried to make an httpcontext by first querying my home page then through the scheduler code and using that as the context but that did not work.

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: application
  Source=Elmah
  ParamName=application
  StackTrace:
       at Elmah.ErrorSignal.Get(HttpApplication application)
       at Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromContext(HttpContext context)
       at Job.Execute(JobExecutionContext context) in Job.cs:line 19
       at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run()
  InnerException: 

ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(new System.Exception());
```

So I am looking for either how to get ELMAH working in this scenario or something comparable to it(something that sends emails, stack trace and everything nice ELMAH has).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/). It's very simple to implement and effective.
You can send [email](http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Mail_target), trace pretty much everything. 
I normally tend to keep everything in a separate config file (NLog.Config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
    <targets>
        <target name="DebugHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${identity} ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
        <target name="ErrorHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
        <target name="FatalHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
        <target name="GenericHandler" type="File" filename="${basedir}/_Logs/${date:format=yyyyMMdd}_${level}.Log"
            layout="${longdate} ${logger}   ${aspnet-session:variable=UserName} ${threadid} ${environment}  ${aspnet-request}   ${message}  ${exception}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" level="Debug" appendTo="DebugHandler" />
        <logger name="*" level="Error" appendTo="ErrorHandler" />
        <logger name="*" level="Fatal" appendTo="FatalHandler" />
        <logger name="*" levels="Info,Warn" appendTo="GenericHandler" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

As you can see you can activate or deactivate the different levels.

I've used it on in my quartz.net jobs as well as a debugging/tracing system and it does its job.

The only limit is you do not have an ELMAH interface, which can be a huge limit sometimes.